# Is it possible to extract the source code of a URL loaded in webview?

Tags: ios, macos, swift2, webkit

This sounds straight forward and I know I'll be told to just get the contents of a url session.  But I specifically want to know if source code can be derived from a browser's final rendering (post-javascript/JSON formatting)

Edit:  I'm having a problem getting post is processed content. When I download the contents of the url using either swift/objective-c or Java, the content string has placeholders for the search results based on Json search prefs. When in a browser, however, the full results page is visible when right clicking and selecting "view source." I need a way to programmatically get this post-js processed content.

EDIT:  I've loaded the code in webView.  Here is my code:

```
func loadAddressURL() {
    let url = "https://www.adomain.com/apath"
    let URL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about this. Do you want to run a JavaScript in WebPage or what ?

Comment: So you don't want the source code, you want the result of executing it. Java doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try Code Different's answer with swift.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `WKWebView`, which is the Apple's [recommended class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:) to embed web view for new code. Then you can execute Javascript through it to get the post-render HTML:

```
// self.webView is a WKWebView

// In viewDidLoad() or applicationDidFinishLaunching()
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML") { innerHTML, error in
        print(innerHTML!)
    }
}
```

Comment: When `webView` loads the URL, the function you've detailed is not called. I've edited my OP to include how I'm loading the URL in `webView`.

Comment: Because you are using `UIWebView` instead of `WKWebView`. Apple recommends the later