# Swift 2 OS X How can I extract the source code of a URL loaded in webview?

Tags: macos, url, webview, swift2, view-source

NOTE: THIS QUESTION IS FOR SWIFT 2, OS X, NOT IOS.

I need a way to programmatically get post-js processed source content (the final source content that is available in a browser's"view source" option).

When programmatically retrieving source content, it has placeholders for the JSON search results instead of the actual results that a browser's "view source" shows.

I'm able to get the page loaded, but don't know how to extract the source content of the loaded URL.

```
func loadAddressURL() {
    let url = "https://url/search"
    let URL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extract the source code of a URL loaded in webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536453/is-it-possible-to-extract-the-source-code-of-a-url-loaded-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
document.createTextNode( document.documentElement.outerHTML );
```

in an Action App Extension to access the URL and return the HTML:

```
Extension point                                 Typical app extension functionality

Action (iOS and macOS; UI and non-UI variants)  Manipulate or view content originating in a host app.
```

**References**

- [App Extension Programming Guide: Handling Common Scenarios - Accessing a web page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW12)
- [ViewSource: view the source of a given page in Safari - Action.js](https://github.com/dominic/ViewSource/blob/master/ViewSourceExt/Action.js)
- [App Extension Programming Guide: App Extensions Increase Your Impact](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/)
- [Swift: Challenges and Opportunity for Language and Compiler Research (pdf)](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-lmandel/lattner.pdf)